# Case insensitive dictionary

Tags: python

I'd like my dictionary to be case insensitive.

I have this example code:

```
text = "practice changing the color"

words = {'color': 'colour',
        'practice': 'practise'}

def replace(words,text):

    keys = words.keys()

    for i in keys:
        text= text.replace(i ,words[i])
    return  text

text = replace(words,text)

print text
```

Output = practise changing the colour

I'd like another string, `"practice changing the Color"`, (where `Color` starts with a capital) to also give the same output.

I believe there is a general way to convert to lowercase using
`mydictionary[key.lower()]` but I'm not sure how to best integrate this into my existing code. (If this would be a reasonable, simple approach anyway).

Comment: @NickT This PEP has been rejected. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/#rejection

Comment: I am probably missing the point, but in a simplistic way: ```words = {'color': 'colour', 'Color': 'Colour', 'practice': 'practise', 'Practice', 'Practise'}```. The most obvious problems that you are going to run into are changing partial words that do not need changing (“Technicolor”) or switching the British English noun form “practice” to the verb form “practise”. Need a proofreader, really.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want a way to key dictionaries in a non case-sensitive fashion, one way would be to subclass dict and overload the setter / getter:

```
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__setitem__(key.lower(), value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__getitem__(key.lower())
```

Comment: Isn't there a special builtin that is called for 'in' as well?

Comment: Here is a complete list of methods that may need overloading: __setitem__, __getitem__, __contains__, get, has_key, pop, setdefault, and update.  __init__ and fromkeys should also possibly be overloaded to make sure the dictionary is initialized properly.  Maybe I'm wrong and somewhere Python promises that get, hash_key, pop, setdefault, update and __init__ will be implemented in terms of __getitem__, __setitem__ and __contains__ if they've been overloaded, but I don't think so.

Comment: added `__contains__, get, and has_key` to the answer since I ended up coding them :)

Comment: This solution is very limited as it doesn't work for a **lot** of common uses of  `dict`. **Don't use it in your code - it will break all but the simplest uses.**
Apparently @MichaelMerchant attempted to add the missing stuff, but moderation dissaproved the changes (same thing happened to me).
I added a new answer which should be usable as a drop-in `dict` replacement [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32888599/277172).

Comment: Like the others said, setdefault as example is broken! "descriptor 'setdefault' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'"

Comment: Better off subclassing `UserDict` than `dict` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#userdict-objects

Answer (score 89):

Just for the record. I found an awesome impementation on [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/):

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v1.2.3/requests/structures.py#L37

Comment: `from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict`

Comment: That might work, but if what you need is just a Case Insensitive Dict, it's silly to add requests as a dependency just for that.

Comment: @santiagobasulto - it's "silly" until the (need-it-to-work/time-till-deadline) ratio goes to infinity

Comment: If you need just the CaseInsensitiveDict you are free to lift just the source-code of that class from the requests project and insert it into your project provided you retain the license properly etc.

Comment: Note: The structure remembers the
    case of the last key to be set, and ``iter(instance)``,
    ``keys()``, ``items()``, ``iterkeys()``, and ``iteritems()``
    will contain case-sensitive keys. However, querying and contains
    testing is case insensitive

Answer (score 88):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082169/277172) wouldn't work for **lots** of cases, so it cannot be used as a drop-in `dict` replacement. Some tricky points in getting a proper `dict` replacement:

- overloading all of the methods that involve keys
- properly handling non-string keys
- properly handling the constructor of the class

The following should work much better:

```py
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):
    @classmethod
    def _k(cls, key):
        return key.lower() if isinstance(key, basestring) else key

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._convert_keys()
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__getitem__(self.__class__._k(key))
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__setitem__(self.__class__._k(key), value)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__delitem__(self.__class__._k(key))
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__contains__(self.__class__._k(key))
    def has_key(self, key):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).has_key(self.__class__._k(key))
    def pop(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).pop(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)
    def get(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).get(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)
    def setdefault(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).setdefault(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)
    def update(self, E={}, **F):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).update(self.__class__(E))
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).update(self.__class__(**F))
    def _convert_keys(self):
        for k in list(self.keys()):
            v = super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).pop(k)
            self.__setitem__(k, v)
```

Comment: This is great, but there is one minor problem. The super definition of `update` is `update(self, E=None, **F)`, meaning `E` is optional. You've re-defined it to make `E` required. Add in the `=None` and this will be perfect.

Comment: Nice catch @NickWilliams. Thanks!

Comment: Python is easy, they said. Python is fun, they said.

Comment: @rr-. To be totally fair, imagine doing this in say C.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure, but it should be straightforward to add. Just modify `_k()` to also normalise as desired.

Comment: return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).setdefault(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: In python 3 the abstract type `basestring` was removed. `str` can be used as a replacement.

Comment: Great answer, and it still works in Python 3, as long as you change basestring to str. I have modified it slightly to support tuples. If a tuple is used as a key, it will match the tuple regardless of case of the items in the tuple (even if nested). It's too long to post as a comment. Basically, if it's a tuple, it calls a method that converts all strings in the tuple to lowercase recursively.

Comment: for those who need python2/3 compatibility with respect to basestring - you can see this answer as a basis for modifying the `_k` method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22679982

Comment: what about encoding every key to its base32 representation? Will that ensure consistency across any encoding the string is in?

Comment: Very similar to what I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457369/281545 - main (important) difference is that I retain case info, but this needs a dedicated string class

Comment: ideally, a true case-insensitive dictionary would also be case-preserving of the last setter.  ie: this is collation only, not data-loss

Comment: In Python 3 it implementing a dictionary subclass would be a lot simpler if its base class was the abstract base class [`collections.abc.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=mutablemapping#collections-abstract-base-classes) because doing so would *greatly* reduce the number of methods that needed to be implemented.

Comment: For python3 only remove the def has_key overload - the existing def __contains__ covers it.

Comment: @m000 Please excuse my Python ignorance, but why is _k defined as a class method and then all the calls use that ugly `self.__class__._k(key)` invocation? Is this trying to avoid overriding in a further subclass or something?

Comment: @jschultz410 Overriding in a subclass should work fine. Going through `__class__` makes sure that the instances of the class will behave the same way. Otherwise you could redefine `_k()` per instance and have instances of CaseInsensitiveDict that don't really behave the same way.
Since this is Python, you can still screw things up if you try hard enough, so this just puts the screw-up barrier a bit higher.

Answer (score 20):

In my particular instance, I needed a case insensitive lookup, however, I did not want to modify the original case of the key. For example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['MyConfig'] = 'value'
>>> d['myconfig'] = 'new_value'
>>> d
{'MyConfig': 'new_value'}
```

You can see that the dictionary still has the original key, however it is accessible case-insensitively. Here's a simple solution:

```
class CaseInsensitiveKey(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key.lower())
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key.lower() == other.key.lower()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

The __hash__ and __eq__ overrides are required for both getting and setting entries in the dictionary. This is creating keys that hash to the same position in the dictionary if they are case-insensitively equal.

Now either create a custom dictionary that initializes a CaseInsensitiveKey using the provided key:

```
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = CaseInsensitiveKey(key)
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = CaseInsensitiveKey(key)
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__getitem__(key)
```

or simply make sure to always pass an instance of CaseInsensitiveKey as the key when using the dictionary.

Comment: Nice, thanks! :) (Note that this class doesn't implement the case-insensitive "dict(iterable)" constructor so if you need it you have to add it)

Comment: You should use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` for comparisons, `self.key.casefold() == other.key.casefold()`, to allow `"ß"` and `"ss"` to equate as true, among others.

Answer (score 15):

Would you consider using `string.lower()` on your inputs and using a fully lowercase dictionary? It's a bit of a hacky solution, but it works

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but I think it is along the lines of what Kim was after.

Comment: This is not hacky. In fact this is the less error-prone way than overriding dictionary class.

Comment: This is great unless you want to preserve the original case when setting the a key the first time.

Comment: use `string.casefold()` instead

Comment: @ErikAronesty link to docs: https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold

Answer (score 6):

I've modified the [simple yet good solution by pleasemorebacon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30221547/151641) (thanks!) making it slightly more compact, self-contained and with minor updates to allow construction from `{'a':1, 'B':2}` and support `__contains__` protocol.
Finally, since the `CaseInsensitiveDict.Key` is expected to be string (what else can be case-sensitive or not), it is a good idea to derive `Key` class from the `str`, then it is possible, for instance, to dump `CaseInsensitiveDict` with `json.dumps` out of the box.

```
# caseinsensitivedict.py
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):

    class Key(str):
        def __init__(self, key):
            str.__init__(key)
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.lower())
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.lower() == other.lower()

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__init__()
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        for key, val in data.items():
            self[key] = val
    def __contains__(self, key):
        key = self.Key(key)
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__contains__(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = self.Key(key)
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = self.Key(key)
        return super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__getitem__(key)
```

Here is a basic test script for those who like to check things in action:

```
# test_CaseInsensitiveDict.py
import json
import unittest
from caseinsensitivedict import *

class Key(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.Key = CaseInsensitiveDict.Key
        self.lower = self.Key('a')
        self.upper = self.Key('A')

    def test_eq(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.lower, self.upper)

    def test_hash(self):
        self.assertEqual(hash(self.lower), hash(self.upper))

    def test_str(self):
        self.assertEqual(str(self.lower), 'a')
        self.assertEqual(str(self.upper), 'A')

class Dict(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.Dict = CaseInsensitiveDict
        self.d1 = self.Dict()
        self.d2 = self.Dict()
        self.d1['a'] = 1
        self.d1['B'] = 2
        self.d2['A'] = 1
        self.d2['b'] = 2

    def test_contains(self):
        self.assertIn('B', self.d1)
        d = self.Dict({'a':1, 'B':2})
        self.assertIn('b', d)

    def test_init(self):
        d = self.Dict()
        self.assertFalse(d)
        d = self.Dict({'a':1, 'B':2})
        self.assertTrue(d)

    def test_items(self):
        self.assertDictEqual(self.d1, self.d2)
        self.assertEqual(
            [v for v in self.d1.items()],
            [v for v in self.d2.items()])

    def test_json_dumps(self):
        s = json.dumps(self.d1)
        self.assertIn('a', s)
        self.assertIn('B', s)

    def test_keys(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.d1.keys(), self.d2.keys())

    def test_values(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            [v for v in self.d1.values()],
            [v for v in self.d2.values()])
```

Comment: You should use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` for comparisons, `self.casefold() == other.key.casefold()` and `hash(self.casefold())`, to allow "ß" and "ss" to equate as true, among others.

Comment: A small addition for nested dictionaries:

Answer (score 4):

You can do a dict key case insensitive search with a one liner:

```
>>> input_dict = {'aBc':1, 'xyZ':2}
>>> search_string = 'ABC'
>>> next((value for key, value in input_dict.items() if key.lower()==search_string.lower()), None)
1
>>> search_string = 'EFG'
>>> next((value for key, value in input_dict.items() if key.lower()==search_string.lower()), None)
>>>
```

You can place that into a function:

```
def get_case_insensitive_key_value(input_dict, key):
    return next((value for dict_key, value in input_dict.items() if dict_key.lower() == key.lower()), None)
```

Note that only the first match is returned.

Answer (score 3):

While a case insensitive dictionary is a solution, and there are answers to how to achieve that, there is a possibly easier way in this case. A case insensitive search is sufficient:

```
import re

text = "Practice changing the Color"
words = {'color': 'colour', 'practice': 'practise'}

def replace(words,text):
        keys = words.keys()
        for i in keys:
                exp = re.compile(i, re.I)
                text = re.sub(exp, words[i], text)
        return text

text = replace(words,text)
print text
```

Comment: It's far better to use the built-in string methods than the regular expression module when the built-ins can easily handle it, which they can in this case.

Comment: thanks calmh. I'm short on time right now, so your quick and simple solution suits me nicely. 

thanks

Comment: @John Y: What would be the regexp-less solution to this? I don't see it.

Comment: Kim already mentioned it:  use the string.lower() method.  Other answers also mentioned it.  Comments are no good for posting code, so I guess I will post my own answer.

Comment: +1 This solution worked best for me, since in my case, the case of the dictionary key matters, and simply lowercasing the key on set is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to do this once in your code (hence, no point to a function), the most straightforward way to deal with the problem is this:

lowercase_dict = {key.lower(): value for (key, value) in original_dict}

I'm assuming here that the dict in question isn't all that large--it might be inelegant to duplicate it, but if it's not large, it isn't going to hurt anything.

The advantage of this over @Fred's answer (though that also works) is that it produces the same result as a dict when the key isn't present:  a KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this problem, each has its set of pros and cons. Just to add to the list (looks like this option wasn't mentioned), it's possible to extend `str` class and use it as a key:

```
class CaseInsensitiveStr(str):
    def __hash__(self) -> 'int':
        return hash(self.lower())
    def __eq__(self, other:'str') -> 'bool':
        return self.lower() == other.lower()
```

It can work well if dictionary in question is private and some kind of interface is used to access it.

```
class MyThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self._d: 'dict[CaseInsensitiveStr, int]' = dict()
    def set(self, key:'str', value:'int'):
        self._d[CaseInsensitiveStr(key)] = value
    def get(self, key:'str') -> 'int':
        return self._d[CaseInsensitiveStr(key)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit: based on @m000's answer. The following variant provides a get_orig_key method, by keeping track of the case-sensitive key of the last "set" operation.

```py
class RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict(dict):
    @classmethod
    def _k(cls, key):
        return key.lower() if isinstance(key, str) else key

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.key_dict = {}
        for key in self.keys():
            if isinstance(key, str):
                self.key_dict[key.lower()] = key
        self._convert_keys()

    def get_orig_key(self, case_ins_key):
        if case_ins_key in self.key_dict:
            return self.key_dict[case_ins_key]
        else:
            return case_ins_key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).__getitem__(self.__class__._k(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            self.key_dict[key.lower()] = key
        super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).__setitem__(self.__class__._k(key), value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).__delitem__(self.__class__._k(key))

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).__contains__(self.__class__._k(key))

    def has_key(self, key):
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).has_key(self.__class__._k(key))

    def pop(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).pop(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).get(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)

    def setdefault(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        if isintance(key, str):
            self.key_dict[key.lower()] = key
        return super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).setdefault(self.__class__._k(key), *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, E={}, **F):
        super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).update(self.__class__(E))
        super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).update(self.__class__(**F))

    def _convert_keys(self):
        for k in list(self.keys()):
            v = super(RobbieCaseInsensitiveDict, self).pop(k)
            self.__setitem__(k, v)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just set up a function to handle this:

```
def setLCdict(d, k, v):
    k = k.lower()
    d[k] = v
    return d

myDict = {}
```

So instead of

```
myDict['A'] = 1
myDict['B'] = 2
```

You can:

```
myDict = setLCdict(myDict, 'A', 1)
myDict = setLCdict(myDict, 'B', 2)
```

You can then either lower case the value before looking it up or write a function to do so.

```
    def lookupLCdict(d, k):
        k = k.lower()
        return d[k]

    myVal = lookupLCdict(myDict, 'a')
```

Probably not ideal if you want to do this globally but works well if its just a subset you wish to use it for.