# Is there a way of subclassing from dict and collections.abc.MutableMapping together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's for the sake of example assume I want to subclass `dict` and have all keys capitalized:

```
class capdict(dict):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwds):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwds)
        mod = [(k.capitalize(),v) for k,v in super().items()]
        super().clear()
        super().update(mod)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return super().__getitem__(key.capitalize())
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        super().__setitem__(key.capitalize(),value)
    def __delitem__(self,key):
        super().__detitem__(key.capitalize())
```

This works to an extent,

```
>>> ex = capdict(map(reversed,enumerate("abc")))
>>> ex
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
>>> ex['a']
0
```

but, of course, only for methods I remembered to implement, for example

```
>>> 'a' in ex
False
```

is not the desired behavior.

Now, the lazy way of filling in all the methods that can be derived from the "core" ones
would be mixing in `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. Only, it doesn't work here. I presume because the methods in question (`__contains__` in the example) are already provided by `dict`.

Is there a way of having my cake and eating it? Some magic to let `MutableMapping` only see the methods I've overridden so that it reimplements the others based on those?

Comment: You may not need to use `MutableMapping`. See [Case insensitive dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082152/case-insensitive-dictionary).

Comment: @martineau thanks, as I said it was only an example.

Comment: You could use `os._Environ`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**What you could do:**

This likely won't work out well (i.e. not the cleanest design), but you could inherit from *MutableMapping* first and then from *dict* second.

Then *MutableMapping* would use whatever methods you've implemented (because they are the first in the lookup chain):

```
>>> class D(MutableMapping, dict):
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            print(f'Intercepted a lookup for {key!r}')
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)


>>> d = D(x=10, y=20)
>>> d.get('x', 0)
Intercepted a lookup for 'x'
10
>>> d.get('z', 0)
Intercepted a lookup for 'z'
0
```

**Better way:**

The cleanest approach (easy to understand and test) is to just inherit from *MutableMapping* and then implement the required methods using a regular dict as the base data store (with composition rather than inheritance):

```
>>> class CapitalizingDict(MutableMapping):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            self.store = {}
            self.update(*args, **kwds)
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            key = key.capitalize()
            return self.store[key]
        def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            key = key.capitalize()
            self.store[key] = value
        def __delitem__(self, key):
            del self.store[key]
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.store)
        def __iter__(self):
            return iter(self.store)
        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.store)


>>> d = CapitalizingDict(x=10, y=20)
>>> d
{'X': 10, 'Y': 20}
>>> d['x']
10
>>> d.get('x', 0)
10
>>> d.get('z', 0)
0
>>> d['w'] = 30
>>> d['W']
30
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn I tried both orders... Out of interest, when I use the "could do" method swapping out all the `super`s for explicit `dict`s then it appears to work, except `len` returns `0`. Where's that coming from?

Comment: The super() call from *\__len_()__* goes to the next in the mro:  ``(D, MutableMapping, dict)``.  That is the *MutableMappiing.__len__()* method which always returns 0.  It wasn't intended to be called directly -- it is always supposed to be overridden.  That's why you have to call ``dict.__len__(self)`` directly.    And that's one of the reasons that I said "this likely won't work out well" ;-)