# Read json key value as insensitive key

Tags: python, json

I need to be able to pull the value of the key 'irr' from this json address in python:

```
IRR = conparameters['components'][i]['envelope'][j]['irr']
```

Even if 'irr' is any oher case, like IRR, Irr... etc.

Is that easy?

Comment: You need to loop through all the keys of the dictionary until you find one that matches `irr` case-insensitively.

Comment: The following provides an example of a case-insensitive dictionary class that could be used to perform this action. It should be possible to recursively apply this data structure if needed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082169/3658702

Comment: @JacobTurpin But if he's getting the data from JSON, is it possible to make `json.loads()` use that dictionary class instead of the standard one?

Comment: @Barmar - why yes, yes it is `json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=CaseInsensitiveDict)`...

Comment: @zwer Cool! Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that does it, you have to search for a matching key.

See [Get the first item from an iterable that matches a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition) for how to write a `first()` function that finds the first element of an iterable that matches a condition. I'll use that in the solution below.

```
cur = conparameters['components'][i]['envelope'][j]
key = first(cur.keys(), lambda k: lower(k) == 'irr')
IRR = cur[key]
```

Comment: I cannot find a first function in my python. Even if I try to Import first from first.

Comment: It's not a built-in function. I gave you a link to another question where you can find definitions of it.

Comment: try:
                        IRR = conparameters['components'][i]['envelope'][j]['irr']
                    except KeyError:
                        IRR = conparameters['components'][i]['envelope'][j]['IRR']

Comment: That only handles `irr` and `IRR`, it doesn't handle other combinations of upper and lower case.